# Spring Mongo Aggregation Project Filter

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having an issue implementing a Filter on a Projection that I have working in the Mongo Shell. I've got a Census object that contains a list of Employees.

```
{
   "_id": "ID",
   "name": "census1",
   "employees": [ {
      "eeId": "EE_ID1"
   }, 
   {
      "eeId": "EE_ID2"
   },
   {
      "eeId": "EE_ID3"
   }
}
```

Realistically this could contain a lot of employees. So I'd like to be able to retrieve the main Census object, and a subset of employees. I've already implemented 'slice', so this is going to be retrieving a set of employees by their eeId.

This works fine:

```
db.census.aggregate( 
    [
        {
            $match: {
                "_id": ObjectId("ID1")
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "censusName": 1,
                "employees" : {
                    $filter : {
                        input: "$employees",
                        as: "employees",
                        cond: { $in: [ "$$employees.eeId", ["EE_ID1", "EE_ID3"]] } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
).toArray()
```

The problem is, I can't get it implemented in Java. Here 'employeeIds' is a String of the IDs I want.

```
MatchOperation matchCensusIdStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("id").is(censusId));
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("censusName")
        .and(Filter.filter("employees")
        .as("employees")
        .by(In.arrayOf(employeeIds).containsValue("employees.eeId")))
.as("employees");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchCensusIdStage, projectStage);

return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Census.class, Census.class).getMappedResults().get(0);
```

For this, no results are returned. I've also tried implementing it with a BasicDBObject but got stuck there too.

EDIT (workaround):
I did get a solution using aggregation but not with the filter on the project. This is what I did:

```
db.parCensus.aggregate( 
// Pipeline
[
    {
        $match: {
            "_id": ObjectId("ID1")
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0, "employee": "$employees"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$employee"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "employee.eeId": { $in: ["EE_ID1", "EE_ID3"] }
        }
    }
]
).toArray()
```

Java Code:

```
    MatchOperation matchCensusIdStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("id").is(censusId));
    ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("censusName").and("employees").as("employee");
    UnwindOperation unwindStage = Aggregation.unwind("employee");
    MatchOperation matchEmployeeIdsStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("employee.eeId").in(employeeIds));

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchCensusIdStage, projectStage, unwindStage, matchEmployeeIdsStage);
```

I know I could add a $group at the end to put it back into one Census object, but I just created a separate CensusEmployee object to store it all.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation query posted in the question post works fine. The MongoDB Spring Data API for the aggregation `ArrayOperators.In` syntax is not clear. I couldn't implement a solution based on this aggregation (and no answers related to on the net).

But, the alternative solution is based on the following aggregation query - and it works fine.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { $unwind: "$employees" },
  { $match: { "employees.eeId": { $in: ["EE_ID1", "EE_ID3"] } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", name: { $first: "$name" }, employees: { $push: "$employees" } } }
] )
```

The Java code:

```
List<String> empsToMatch = Arrays.asList("EE_ID1", "EE_ID3");

MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    unwind("employees"),
    match(Criteria.where("employees.eeId").in(empsToMatch )),
    group("_id")
        .first("name").as("name")
        .push("employees").as("employees")
 );

AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "collection", Document.class);
```

Comment: Right, the ArrayOperators.In is what I tried to find a solution with. I'll edit my question with what I finally got working, but I'm hoping someone can help with how to use ArrayOperators.In.