# Check if a value exists in an array, MongoDB bind projection using spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a more complex aggregation query when I try to bind my result using projections, I need to check that Array contains a date (day).

MongoDB query works fine

```
{ "$project" : { "days" : { "day" : "$_id" , "signatureVerified" : {"$in": ["$_id", "$signatureVerified"] } }}}
```

spring-data-code

```
  project().and(DAYS).nested(bind(DAY, _ID)and(Field field));
```

I've tried preparing a match array checker using an ArrayOperators class but there is no possibility to return a Field object. Any ideas on how it can be achieved?

```
  ArrayOperators.arrayOf(SIGNATURE_VERIFIED).containsValue(Fields.field(_ID));
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with the `$in` aggregation array operator used in Spring Data MongoDB API - possible it might be a bug. This is the second time I am encountering this issue. See this post: [Spring Mongo Aggregation Project Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534419/spring-mongo-aggregation-project-filter/60537881#60537881)

Comment: @prasad_ not exactly I have a problem with preparing the correct aggregation object. In the spring-data when you use "ProjectionOperation.nested" and "ProjectionOperation.bind" you are not allowed to use "and" method with "AgreggationExpresion" parameter instead "Field" should be used