# Spring Boot MongoDB Aggregation $in not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MongoDB in a reactive Spring Boot application (using Webflux) and I want to do an aggregation on one of our collections but it is just returning an empty list. The code below shows the aggregation and the equivalent query in the command line.

Running the aggregation in the command line works fine and after testing the code it seems to only be the `.in(users)` part that is not working. So if I just use  `Criteria.where("_id").is("de28b2fa-4c9b-49fa-b29f-d8ad9d270c36")` then a User will be returned.

```
    public Flux<User> findAllInIdList(List<UUID> users, long skip, long limit, Sort.Direction direction) {
        
        List<AggregationOperation> aggs = new ArrayList<>();
        aggs.add(match(Criteria.where("_id").in(users)));
        aggs.add(sort(direction, Fields.CREATED_ON.getValue()));
        aggs.add(Aggregation.skip(skip));
        aggs.add(Aggregation.limit(limit));
        
        TypedAggregation<User> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(User.class, aggs);
        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User.class);

    }

db.User.aggregate([
    {"$match" : {"_id" : {"$in" : ["de28b2fa-4c9b-49fa-b29f-d8ad9d270c36", "9f80bd61-be4d-4b3f-b78f-6172d88165b8", "f33e4769-a9d4-41d2-9f57-ac94afe932d7", "357397d8-ef12-42db-92cd-2cf5c31405ed", "5fc8acb6-c73e-4e8e-91b6-1347317da78b"]}}},
    {"$sort" : {"record.createdOn" : 1}},
    {"$skip" : 0},
    {"$limit" : 50}
])
```

I also have other aggregations in the same class that work fine :

```
    public Flux<User> findAll(long skip, long limit, Sort.Direction direction) {

        List<AggregationOperation> aggs = new ArrayList<>();
        aggs.add(sort(direction, Fields.CREATED_ON.getValue()));
        aggs.add(Aggregation.skip(skip));
        aggs.add(Aggregation.limit(limit));
        TypedAggregation<User> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(User.class, aggs);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User.class);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

As prasad pointed out in the comments the id in the DB are String types so I've also tried mapping the UUIDs in the code to a string and it still returns nothing:

```
public Flux<User> findAllWithCompany(List<UUID> users, long skip, long limit, Sort.Direction direction) {

    List<AggregationOperation> aggs = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> idsAsString = users.stream().map(UUID::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
    aggs.add(match(Criteria.where("_id").in(idsAsString)));
    aggs.add(sort(direction, Fields.CREATED_ON.getValue()));
    aggs.add(Aggregation.skip(skip));
    aggs.add(Aggregation.limit(limit));

    TypedAggregation<User> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(User.class, aggs);
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User.class);

}
```

**EDIT**

Adding additional information:

User entity:

```
@Value
@Jacksonized
@Document(collection = "Users")
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(def = "{'id' : 1, 'record': 1}"),
})
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@MongoId(targetType = FieldType.STRING)
UUID id;
@NonNull Person person;
Notification notification; // Not stored in DB
@NonNull Security security;


Record record;

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return isEnabled();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return isEnabled();
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return isEnabled();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return Objects.equals(this.security.status.getCode(), Fields.ACTIVE.getValue());
}

@Override
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return security.hashPassword;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.person.email;
}

@Value
@Document
@Jacksonized
@lombok.Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
public static class Person {
    @NonNull String firstName;
    @NonNull String lastName;
    String givenName;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @NonNull String email;
    Set<String> phones;
    String pictureUrl;
}

@Value
@Document
@Jacksonized
@lombok.Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
public static class Security {
    @NonNull String hashPassword;
    @NonNull StatusRef status;
    Instant securityLoggedOn;
    Instant securityLastLoggedOn;
}


@Value
@Document
@Jacksonized
@lombok.Builder(builderClassName = "Builder", toBuilder = true)
public static class Notification {
    Set<UserAlerts.Alerts> alerts;
    Set<String> subscribedAlertTypes;
}
}
```

Example record in the Database:

```
    {
      "_id": "6bee42cc-1a16-11ec-9621-0242ac130002",
      "person": {
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "1",
        "givenName": "Test user",
        "email": "test@onepointltd.com",
        "phones": [
          "+91-1234566",
          "+91-1234566"
        ],
        "picture": "https://picsum.photos/nik.jpg"
      },
      "notification": {},
      "security": {
        "hashPassword": "cBrlgyL2GI2GINuLUUwgojITuIufFycpLG4490dhGtY=",
        "securityLoggedOn": 2021-09-23T07:36:21.330+00:00,
        "securityLastLoggedOn": 2021-09-23T07:36:21.330+00:00,
        "status": {
          "code": "active",
          "changedBy": "416bad39-02c5-45a5-802f-4a33cd24a2ee",
          "changedOn": 2021-09-23T07:36:21.330+00:00
        }
      },
      "record": {
        "createdOn": 2021-09-23T07:36:21.330+00:00,
        "createdBy": "416bad39-02c5-45a5-802f-4a33cd24a2ee",
        "updatedOn": 2021-09-23T07:36:21.330+00:00,
        "updatedBy": "416bad39-02c5-45a5-802f-4a33cd24a2ee"
      }
    }
```

Comment: `{"$match" : {"_id" : {"$in" : ["de28b2fa-4c9b-49fa-b29f-d8ad9d270c36",...]`,  - your command-line code is using a string array to match. But, your Spring Data MongoDB aggregation is using `List<UUID>` objects to match. If the data is the same, the you can try matching a `List<String>` rather than the `List<UUID>` objects.

Comment: @prasad_ I've updated my question to take your comment into account. I did try this out but still returned no results.

Comment: The `User` POJO class with the fields used in the query - please post that also. Isee the syntax and usage is correct: `match(Criteria.where("_id").in(idsAsString))`

Comment: You can as well post a sample document (from the database collection) showing the fields used.

Comment: Added  both of the above

Comment: `match(Criteria.where("_id").in(idsAsString))` - may be try with using the `id` instead of `_id`?

Comment: "_id" works fine if I use something like `match(Criteria.where("_id").is("6bee42cc-1a16-11ec-9621-0242ac130002"))` it's the `.in()` part that seems not to work. I'll try just using `"id"` just in case though.

Comment: Here is some Spring Data MongoDB sample code using the `in` operator (a SO post): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534419/spring-mongo-aggregation-project-filter/60537881#60537881

Comment: Wow, that worked. I don't understand what was different from what I've done previously though. Do I answer my own post now then or do you want to do that @prasad_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works based on @prasad_'s comment linking the following post: [Spring Mongo Aggregation Project Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534419/spring-mongo-aggregation-project-filter/60537881#60537881)

I just adapted this code to my reactive/webflux solution.

```
public Flux<User> findAllWithCompany(List<UUID> users, long skip, long limit, Sort.Direction direction) {
  List<String> ids = users.stream().map(UUID::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

  Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("_id").in(ids )),
        sort(direction, Fields.CREATED_ON.getValue()),
        skip(skip),
        limit(limit)
  );

  return mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Users", User.class);
}
```